# Personalized Author Area

Tags: plugins, users, author

I have most of a site together that is set up to allow people to register as authors and post stories. I had originally suggested we use a form and have the client create the post, since he  also wishes for people to add audio and images  However, he says he wants it so any Author can add/edit/post anything (don't even get me started on security). I decided   to let people register,  then  send them to a how-to page describing how to create a post, upload an image and add audio file, with screen shot pics. Not the best solution but in budget.  Now my client wants this:

*What I would like it to be is more of a personalized page.  So I would have my pic in the upper left corner and then some information about myself.  In the page we would then set up sections that show different types of content for that person.  There will be a story section, a picture gallery and a media.  I'm guessing that we'll want to have those link to a page that can show them in better organization than we can show on the person's home page (for lack of a better term for it at the moment).*

I personally don't see a cheap or easy way to do this, unless if there is a plugin out there that adds this sort of functionality. But beyond that, has anyone run into this and, if so, how did you solve this personalized page issue? I just don't know how to dumb this down any further for users without massive changes to the system.  I'm guessing "knowing about it from the beginning" would have been the best solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always the same with those clients ... :-)

Unfortunately your requirements sound pretty custom. Only advise I can give you is to use one of the custom field plugins like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) or [Types](http://wp-types.com). Those can speed up the development of custom pages like you have by a factor of 10, as you don't need to program all the form handling, but just need to configure the forms and create the templates for outputting the info.